# How do I get GPS information from Polar's Accesslink API?

Tags: python, api, gps, location

I have recently started developing an application to analyse my all-time exercises in the Polar platform.

I'm using their [Accesslink API](https://www.polar.com/accesslink-api/#how-to-get-started) to get new sessions and I have exported my old sessions through another service they offer.

The exported sessions come with fully detailed information (instant GPS location, speed, heart rate), but the JSON data provided by the API is just a summary. I am looking for a way to get the initial position (GPS location) of my session to, later, find the city's name from another source. I think that the only way to do this is by getting the GPS info of my sessions.

Although the sessions have a **has-route** field, I cannot find in their documentation a way to request this route. They have provided a [working example](https://github.com/polarofficial/accesslink-example-python), but it does not provide a way to get these data.

Does anyway know if this is possible and, if so, could you please give me some directions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the GPS information is provided through GPX files, which are provided by the API mentioned on the question. There is a method implemented to do this on their github (link also on the question) which already performs this task. I have added the call to this method and saved its output [in this project](https://github.com/mendelson/polar-fitness-data-analysis).